# Unordered list in HTML5 with a list/group name

Tags: html, html-lists

How would you create an unordered list of items in HTML5 with a group name at the top? The items should look indented.

Ex:

```
GroupName1
    Item1
    Item2
    Item3
GroupName2
    Item4
    Item5
```

Comment: Have a look at the right of the question box: *indent code by 4 spaces*. Seems you could achieve this effect with a nested list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do a list within a list?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Group 1
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Group 2
    <ul>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I reckon [scurker’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457199/unordered-list-in-html5-with-a-list-group-name/6457267#6457267) is the way to go, but if your groups were really separate from each other, and thus didn’t really make sense in one big list, you could do this:

```
<section>
    <h1>GroupName1</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Item1</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
        <li>Item3</li>
    </ul>
</section>

<section>
    <h1>GroupName2</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>Item4</li>
        <li>Item5</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```